# Locale code for iPhone's localizable strings

Tags: iphone, localization

What's the locale code for traditional Chinese and French Canadian to be used for iPhone localizable strings file.  I know the code for simplified Chinese and French, which is zh and fr, but not its counterpart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experiments, I found out that the locale code used to name the localization strings file for Chinese are:

zh_hant (traditional)

zh_hans (simplified)

Comment: in iOS7 it is zh-Hant and zh-Hans

Answer (score 3):

Set it on your device and execute

```
NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your language in the iPhone Simulator (though 'Settings').  The following code will show the language code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Current language: %@", currentLanguage);
```